# understand haskell logic behind odd's and even's index lists

Tags: list, haskell, logic, haskell-stack, haskell-platform

I had a question in haskell that asks a function to divide a list in two different lists so the even indexs filled a list and the odd ones another.
Example:

```
func :: [Int] -> ([Int], [Int])
```

Then, if we enter with [44,8,11,23], we expected receive [44,11] and [8,23].
Looking in the internet I found a great and geniaus solution but can't understand the logic behind it:

```
func :: [Int] -> ([Int], [Int])
func [] = ([], [])
func [x] = ([x], [])
func (x:y:xs) = (x:odds, y:evens)
    where
    (odds, evens) = func xs
```

I know that there are "odd" and "even" functions in haskell, but what would mean "odd**s**" and "even**s**".
How tha values go righty to the certain list?
I am drowning in doubt because of this.

I am looking in severals foruns and tutorials to try understand the logic of this code but I am in the zero level until now.

Comment: `where (odds, evens) = func xs`: `odds` and `evens` are just the return from the recursive call. And it's getting odd and even indexed elements just via destructuring: `(x:y:xs)`.

Comment: `odds` and `evens` are just variable names that the person who wrote this code decided to use. They could have used anything else, like `oddIndicesList` and `evenIndicesList`.

Comment: Ok, i got it. So the code is saying that the answer is a tuple where the first list start with 'x' and is appended by something (odds) and the second list start with 'y' and is appeded by something (evens). I think my question is focused in the last line. I don't get it. What is the logic of '(odds, evens) = func xs', what the code is saying?

Comment: I think that in practice, a simpler single expression could be used, based on a suitable library function such as [foldr](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr), thus pushing the recursion into the runtime library. But is that easier to understand ? A matter of opinion, I guess. Code being like: `func = foldr  (\n (as,bs) -> (n:bs, as))  ([],[])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that there are "odd" and "even" functions in haskell, but what would mean "odd**s**" and "even**s**".

`odds` & `evens` are just variable names. They’re not directly related to the `odd` & `even` functions. They’re plural (ending in `s`) because that’s the Haskell naming convention for lists.

Let’s work step-by-step through your example input, starting with `func [44, 8, 11, 23]`.

Since this is a recursive function, there will be multiple calls to `func`, with their own local variables. To avoid confusion, I will add numbers to the local variables for each call, e.g. `x1` and `x2` instead of just `x`.

First, `func [44, 8, 11, 23]` matches the third clause of `func`, `func (x : y : xs)`.

```
let
  x1 = 44
  y1 = 8
  xs1 = [11, 23]
  (odds1, evens1) = func xs1
in (x1 : odds1, y1 : evens1)
```

This can be simplified a bit.

```
let
  (odds1, evens1) = func [11, 23]
in (44 : odds1, 8 : evens1)
```

Now we need to know the value of `func [11, 23]`. This also matches the third clause.

```
let
  (odds1, evens1) = let
    x2 = 11
    y2 = 23
    xs2 = []
    (odds2, evens2) = func xs2
    in (x2 : odds2, y2 : evens2)
in (44 : odds1, 8 : evens1)
```

And again we can simplify.

```
let
  (odds1, evens1) = let
    (odds2, evens2) = func []
    in (11 : odds2, 23 : evens2)
in (44 : odds1, 8 : evens1)
```

Finally, `func []` matches the first clause, `func [] = ([], [])`.

```
let
  (odds1, evens1) = let
    (odds2, evens2) = ([], [])
    in (11 : odds2, 23 : evens2)
in (44 : odds1, 8 : evens1)
```

So we can continue simplifying until we get a solution.

```
let
  (odds1, evens1) = let
    odds2 = []
    evens2 = []
    in (11 : odds2, 23 : evens2)
in (44 : odds1, 8 : evens1)
```

```
let
  (odds1, evens1) = (11 : [], 23 : [])
in (44 : odds1, 8 : evens1)
```

```
let
  odds1 = 11 : []
  evens1 = 23 : []
in (44 : odds1, 8 : evens1)
```

```
(44 : 11 : [], 8 : 23 : [])
```

```
([44, 11], [8, 23])
```

Comment: Unbelievablely enlightening! Thank you for the answer and explanation step by step! Now i am getting better whats is going on!

Answer (score 3):

Piece by piece:

```
func (x:y:xs) = ...
```

When the input has length >=2, starting with `x` and `y` and then continuing with the list xs ...

```
          ... = (x:odds, y:evens)
```

... the result is a pair, whose first component is `x : odds` and the second component is `y : evens`. The variables `odds` and `evens` are defined as ...

```
    where
    (odds, evens) = func xs
```

... those (list) values which result from the recursive call `func xs`.

---

Let's make an example:

```
func [1,2,3,4] =
func (1:2:xs) =   -- with xs = [3,4]
(1:odds, 2:evens) 
where (odds, evens) = func xs = func [3,4]
```

To complete the computation, we then compute the recursive call:

```
func [3,4] =
func (3:4:xs2) =  -- with xs2 = []
(3:odds2, 4:odds2)
where (odds2, evens2) = func xs2 = func []
```

One more recursive call to compute, but that's immediate: `func [] = ([], [])`.

So, we have

```
(odds2, evens2) = func [] = ([],[])
-- hence
odds2 = evens2 = []
```

Having discovered that, we obtain from the previous equation:

```
func [3,4] = (3:[], 4:[]) = ([3], [4])
```

So, we have

```
(odds, even) = ([3], [4])
-- hence
odds = [3]
evens = [4]
```

so we obtain from the even older equation:

```
func [1,2,3,4] = (1:odds, 2:evens) = (1:[3], 2:[4]) = ([1,3], [2,4])
```

Comment: Thank you for answer and explain step by step the recursion! It helped a lot to understand what happens behing the scene!